# Qt, set individual matrix elements of QTransform

Tags: qt

Is there a way to set the the m_ij elements individualy in a QTransform without redefining the whole matrix ?

(e.g. reseting only the translation part)

Comment: Obtain current values with `QTransform::m11` and similar methods, replace those you need to change, and use `QTransform::setMatrix` to set new values.

Answer (score 0):

You'd use the `rotate`, `scale`, `shear` and `translate` operations to indirectly change the relevant elements.

If you only want to change the translation, you can easily do so for some kinds of transforms.

```
void setTranslation(QTransform & t, qreal x, qreal y) {
  Q_ASSERT(t.type() != QTransform::TxRotate && t.type() != QTransform::TxShear && t.type() != QTransform::TxProject);

  x -= t.m31() / m11();
  y -= t.m32() / m22();
  t.translate(x, y);
}
```

You have to understand, though, that the elements interact and the "translation" that you set may not always act the way you think it will.

Comment: I know, the 3x3 matrix for 2D transform is a trick to get the translation to work with product, but I find it really strange that we can't set the attributes individually... I would have expected the mij accessors as references